# How to configure Apache/Subersion Path based using LDAP/Limit and AuthzSVNAccessFile

Tags: apache, svn

I have an apache based subversion server that hosts multiple repositories that has been working just fine using Location stanza's that make use of Limit and LimitExcept sections as shown below:

```
<Location "/svn/IAM/">
  <Limit GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
    Require ldap-group CN=LDAP_ReadOnly
  </Limit>
  <LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
    Require ldap-group CN=LDAP_ReadWrite
  </LimitExcept>
</Location>
```

Based on this, accounts that are in LDAP_ReadOnly are able to read the entire repo, and accounts that are in LDAP_ReadWrite are able read and write to the entire repo.

Along comes the need to grant group LDAP_LimitedRead Read access to "/svn/IAM/Trunk/Project1 AND no access to /svn/IAM/Trunk/Project1/one.properties and also no access to /svn/IAM/Trunk/Project2 and so on.

I have tried the following with SVNParentPath, and SVNPath

```
<Location "/svn/IAM/Trunk/Project1/">
        Dav svn
        SVNParentPath /svn/repos/IAM/Trunk/Project1
        AuthzSVNAccessFile IAM.svnAuth
</Location>
```

with the following in the IAM.svnAuth file

```
[IAM:Trunk/Project1]
Dev1 = r

[IAM:Trunk/Project1/one.properties]
Dev1 =
```

As per the redbean book, path based auth only points to the use of AuthzSVNAccessFile. What i'd like to know is if its possible to do both, and how.

Answer (score 0):

Path based authorisation can be done via group/user

Create groups

[groups]
readonly-developers = harry, sally, joe

readwrite-developers = frank, sally, jane

everyone = harry, sally, joe, frank, jane

Groups can be granted access control just like users. Distinguish them with an “at” (@) prefix:

[reponame1:/projects/calc]

@readwrite-developers = rw

[reponame2:/projects/paint]

@readonly-developers = r

frank =rw;